Book that features clones used for retirement
Trying to find a book I read years ago. The main premise was that clones were used for people to live on Earth while the original person retired on the moon.
There were two main characters. One was an older author who was wanting to retire. She made a clone of herself to live on Earth and continue writing. The original went to the moon retirement community to live out the rest of her life. Issues arise because her children want her royalty money when she dies, but since she has a clone, when is she considered dead?
The other character is a younger man with a terminal illness. He gets cloned to live on Earth with out his disease. The original also goes to live on the moon retirement community. But after he is cloned a cure is found. So is he allowed to get the cure and move back to Earth, or is his clone now legally him and in charge of his life?
The authors name might have started with a W or Z. I remember I found it near the end of the science fiction section of the library.

In roughly which year did you read this?

This is Robert J. Sawyer's 2005 novel Mindscan.
Quoting the blurb on the 2006 Tor mass-market paperback (emphasis mine):

Jake Sullivan has cheated death: he's discarded his doomed biological body and copied his consciousness into an android form. The new Jake soon finds love, something that eluded him when he was encased in flesh: he falls for the android version of Karen, a woman rediscovering all the joys of life now that she's no longer in a worn-out body either.
But Karen's son sues, claiming that she has done him out of his inheritance. In the courtroom and on the lunar surface, where the original Jake has gone to die, the future of uploaded humanity hangs in the balance.
Mindscan is vintage Sawyer—a feast for the mind and the heart.

A short quote from Jake's discussion with the administrator of High Eden (Brian Hades) after the cure is discovered:

"I have to return to Earth."
Hades raised his eyebrows. "We can't allow that.  You know the rules."
"You don't understand," I said.  "They've found a cure for my problem."
[...]
Hades's voice was infinitely solicitous. "Sir, I'm sorry. We'll certainly arrange for you to have this cure—and right away, since I understand how precarious your current health is. But you can't leave here."

